# Rails - dynamic method creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two methods that are identical apart from the ActiveRecord class they are referencing:

```
def category_id_find(category_name)
  category = Category.find_by_name(category_name)
  if category != nil
    return category.id
  else
    return nil
  end
end

def brand_id_find(brand)
  brand = Brand.find_by_name(brand)
  if brand != nil
    return brand.id
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

Now, I just know there must be a more Railsy/Ruby way to combine this into some kind of dynamically-created method that takes two arguments, the class and the string to find, so I tried (and failed) with something like this:

```
def id_find(class, to_find)
  thing = (class.capitalize).find_by_name(to_find)
  if thing.id != nil
    return thing.id
  else
    return nil
  end
end
```

which means I could call `id_find(category, "Sports")`

I am having to populate tables during seeding from a single, monster CSV file which contains all the data.  So, for example, I am having to grab all the distinct categories from the CSV, punt them in a Category table then then assign each item's category_id based on the id from the just-populated category table, if that makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class` is a reserved keyword in Ruby (it's used for class declarations only), so you can't use it to name your method parameter. Developers often change it to `klass`, which preserves the original meaning without colliding with this restriction. However, in this case, you'll probably be passing in the name of a class as a string, so I would call it `class_name`.

Rails' ActiveSupport has a number of built in inflection methods that you can use to turn a string into a constant. Depending on what your CSV data looks like, you might end up with something like this:

```
def id_find(class_name, to_find)
  thing = (class_name.camelize.constantize).find_by_name(to_find)
  ...
end
```

Comment: constantize - my gogole-fu must be way off - exactly what I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If using a string, you can use constantize instead of capitalize and your code should work (in theory):

```
thing = passed_in_class.constantize.find_by_name(to_find)
```

But you can also pass the actual class itself to the method, no reason not to:

```
thing = passed_in_class.find_by_name(to_find)
```